# Sublime Text 3 (Fedora 22) Can view packages but they don't install

Tags: fedora

Trying to install phpfmt, when I go package control > install package > click phpfmt the window closes and nothing actually happens. I successfully installed ctags the day I started using Fedora but now I can't install any packages.

Is there a way to manually install phpfmt without using package manager or anything I can do to diagnose the issue?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if you have installed the package controller? 
It's not installed as default. Information on how to install can be found [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).